# Using expression and paste in R to format an ion name with units in parantheses

Tags: r

I want to create a clean label to a graph that has the species abbreviation of an ion (in this case Chloride) followed by the concentration units (micro equivalents per liter) enclosed in parentheses. As written, the code mostly produces this, but superscripts the parentheses/units section. Probably missing something small. Using this code snippet with the ylab() command in ggplot2 as a label. Thanks.

My code so far:

```
cl.label = expression(paste(Cl^- ~(mu~eq ~L^-1)), parse=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the expression, `-` is an operator so it needs something to "negate." You can give it a phantom object like

```
cl.label = expression(Cl^-phantom() ~(mu~eq ~L^-1))
```

or you can treat the `-` as a literal dash value with

```
cl.label = expression(Cl^"-" ~(mu~eq ~L^-1))
```

Comment: This is excellent. Thanks so much! I like that the phantom object gives a bit of extra spacing as well. Both work awesome. Again, thanks.

Comment: Or `plot(1, xlab=quote(Cl^"-"~(mu~eq~L^-1)))`

Comment: This is how I do such things, though you probably just want `phantom()` so you don't leave extra space for the imaginary `1`. Note also, you don't need the `paste()` here or `parse = TRUE`: `expression(Cl^-phantom(1) ~(mu~eq ~L^-1))` is sufficient.

Comment: Finally, do note that there is a (big) difference between `-` and `"-"` in the expression when rendered. If you worry about typography, the quoted version may not be what you want. `expression(Cl^-phantom() ~ (mu ~ eq ~ L^-1))` would be my preferred way.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I was being lazy and just focusing on the "-". I've updated based on your comments.